# accidently deleted R.java by using clean by ecclipse how do i regenerate R.java back

Tags: android

My R.Java was not updating properly, thats what I thought, so I cleaned the code and builded it but it resaulted the R.java file to be deleted. How do I regenerate the file back im kinda lost.

Comment: It should rebuild when you rebuild the project.

Comment: Try to clean and then build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Just refresh the project / do build / rebuild project.
2. If that doesn't work try deleting all the gen tree in your project.
3. If that doesn't work try closing eclipe and reopen.

rebuild option under Project > Clean and then select the project you want to clean up... that's all
make sure that Build Automatically is marked, or if not then select the build project.

R.java is a generated file, once you do one of those, it will create the R.java for you.

Comment: how do i do that go to project/build project ?

Comment: John, I gave the answer a vote up because this is what we've all grown used to and you should definitely try this in the future. It could also be the r22 "build-tools" issue as well as an XML file error.

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/
 question_text_view').

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw an additional thing to check. All of the answers here are traditionally correct. If you've upgraded to SDK r22 there's a new one. Go in to your SDK manager and make sure that you have installed:

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools

I was able to figure this out after finally reverting back to using ant to do the build.

Another old issue that can cause you to have problems is an error in one of your XML files. If the res directory or any of the files in there or your manifest have a red error marker, fix the error there and then try doing a project clean/rebuild.